# My App Is Crashing When Sometimes Accessing The Game Center

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've had this bug for a while on one of my apps, what's happening is when my app moves to the storyboard to show the best score/submit to game center, it sometimes crashes, mostly when a new high score is ready to be submitted to game center. I've done a bit of reading and this seems to be a common bug in iOS 9.

Surely there is a fix for this particular bug:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GKInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'A GKScore must specify a leaderboard.'
```

My code:

```
if (_gameCenterEnabled) {
    NSLog(@"hi it is %@", _leaderboardIdentifier);
    GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];
    score.value = [points.text intValue];

    [GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
```